# How to define express routes to get data in day by day in NodeJS like producthunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have a MERN stack app. Right now, I get all the posts from the database and show in React. However, I want to show only posts that are created on the current date by default, and then if user scroll down, react will request for more information for the previous day, so on and so on. Just like in [producthunt](https://www.producthunt.com).

I have 2 questions
1) Since I don't know how many posts are created on each day, I cannot use the specific position of scroll to define at which point should I call the next route for more data. How do I know when to request for more data?
2) I don't know how to define these routes. Should I have only one route and request for more and more data from database. Or have multiples routes for each day? That really sounds like a lot of routes.

Get all the posts

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find();
    res.json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.send(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the need, flow should be something like this.

1. Get data for current date using the API route by filtering Post by post_time
2. Display all this data.
3. When user reaches end of page request again by sending which date posts you need in the body to same API.
4. Go to step 2.

How should you really approaching this?

I would say fetch fixed number of posts, say 30, when user exhausts all this posts fetch next 30 and so on. It is called lazy loading in the frontend and paging for mongoose.

```
Post.find().skip(30).limit(30);
```